# Django Error - ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'company'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm currently writing an application in django called account, now everything was working fine (as it usually happens), but I had to add more information in my models.py file, and all of the sudden, I got problems running the migrations, certainly as django enthusiast the usual approach is to delete all the migrations in the migration folder, delete the Database and finally run the usual set of commands.

Unfurtunetely this time, that trick is not solving my problem, and I'm getting the following error:

ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'company'.

That error appears when I type python manage.py migrate, the run migration runs without problems, and a migration 0001 file and a database is created, but I still get the error when running the migrate command.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from phone_field import PhoneField
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)
    role = models.TextField(blank=True)
    location = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

class Company(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company

class Client(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="company")
    position = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=100, default="this_is@n_example.com")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    phone = PhoneField(default="(XX)-XXX-XXX")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.firstname}'

class Leads(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
                ('Illumination Studies','Illumination Studies'),
                ('Training','Training'),
                ('Survey Design','Survey Design'),
                ('Software License','Software License')
               )
    STATUS = (('Open','Open'),
               ('Closed','Closed'),
               ('Canceled', 'Canceled')
              )
    project_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="company")
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="agent")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    point_of_contact = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    expected_revenue = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
    expected_licenses = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS)
    estimated_closing_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    services = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CHOICES)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.company}'


class CallReport(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
                ('Video Conference','Video Conference'),
                ('Phone Call','Phone Call'),
                ('Lunch Meeting', 'Lunch Meeting'),
                ('Client Offices', "Client Offices")
               )
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="company")
    minutes_of_meeting = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    client_POC = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='client')

    date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    ACTeQ_representative = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='agent')


    def __str__(self):
        return f'Call Report for {self.company}, on the {self.date}'

class Deal(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Leads, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='id')
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="agent")
    service = models.ForeignKey(Leads, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='service')
    closing_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='client')
    licenses = models.ForeignKey(Leads,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='licenses')
    revenue = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 tial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1823, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'company'


ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'company'.
```

Any ideas?, please refrain yourself from suggesting deleting the db, migrations files, yes of course that solves some issues in particular when a table is added, then obviously the DB has not knowledge of that, but in this case, that trick won't fix the issue

Comment: `company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="company")` Foreign keys are typically integers that point to primary keys in other models.  But here you're using a default value of a string "company".  What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Hi, well not really, that is a default value, I have removed the default value string "company" and the error persist, but thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option `default='company'` in `Client`, `Leads` and `CallReport` must be the error, make sure to remove it and then run the following commands:

```py
python manange.py makemigrations
```

And after that run the following:

```py
python manage.py migrate
```

When you define a relationship in django models, you can not add a type string in a relationship that is pointing to another model.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed fix it, but I had to remove the database and the migration file, could you please expand the reason

Comment: I'm not sure why you was force to remove the migrations and the database, but I have some clue about it, probably your models have some rows in `Client`, `Leads` and `CallReport` and you was adding the field company to them, in those cases you need to put some defaut value to that existing rows. In this case you can use `null=True` to allow those existing rows to be without a company and not delete the database nether the existing rows. That's is the one reason that found to force you to remove migrations and database.

Answer (score 0):

"A ForeignKey contains the primary key of the target table. If the primary key of that table relating to the company value is an integer, then your default value must be that integer", not that string

then, Remember to delete the database, and the migrations inside the migrations folder, and Then

```
python manange.py makemigrations
```

Run the following:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

This should resolve your issue.